# numpy: search of the first and last index in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I use Python with `numpy`.

I have a numpy array `b`:

```
b = np.array([True,True,True,False,False,True,True,False,True,True,True,True,False])
```

I need to find  the first and last index where `b` is equal `True`.

For this exsample:

```
out_index: [0,2]
           [5,6]
           [8,11]
```

Can someone please suggest, **how do I get `out_index`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
b = np.array([True,True,True,False,False,True,True,False,True,True,True,True,False])
idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.r_[False, b, False])).reshape(-1, 2)
idx[:, 1] -= 1
print idx
```

output:

```
[[ 0  2]
 [ 5  6]
 [ 8 11]]
```